# Karate: Weird matching behaviour JSON

Tags: karate

I've stumbled uppon a JSON matching behaviour that doesn't make sense for me at all, because if I execute my feature via parallel runner, the matching fails (which shouldn't). But if I run the feature standalone (in IntelliJ, run feature), the matching succeeds as expected. I am almost losing my mind over this. :)

This is the actual response I get from an REST call:

```
[
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL123",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Gebaeudeteil",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": null,
    "surname": null,
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": null,
  "typeText": null,
  "part": "FeH",
  "partText": "Fernsprechh�uschen",
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": "vor Telekom",
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": null,
  "levelText": null,
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": null,
  "floorText": null,
  "flatNumber": null,
  "flatInfo": null
}
},
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL456",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Wohnung",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": "Karl",
    "surname": "Schaefer",
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": "M",
  "typeText": "Mehrfamilienhaus",
  "part": null,
  "partText": null,
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": null,
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": "EG",
  "levelText": "Erdgescho�",
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": "R",
  "floorText": "rechts",
  "flatNumber": "12",
  "flatInfo": null
}
},
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL789",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Gebaeudeteil",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": null,
    "surname": null,
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": null,
  "typeText": null,
  "part": "VH",
  "partText": "Vorderhaus",
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": "gelbe Haus mit dem h�sslichen Dach",
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": null,
  "levelText": null,
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": null,
  "floorText": null,
  "flatNumber": null,
  "flatInfo": null
}
}
]
```

And this is the JSON I use for matching. It's actually the copied actual response with some fuzzy matching expressions I used because I thought the special chars (ä, ß) could be the problem):

```
[
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL123",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Gebaeudeteil",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": null,
    "surname": null,
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": null,
  "typeText": null,
  "part": "FeH",
  "partText": "#notnull",
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": "vor Telekom",
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": null,
  "levelText": null,
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": null,
  "floorText": null,
  "flatNumber": null,
  "flatInfo": null
}
},
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL456",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Wohnung",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": "Karl",
    "surname": "Schaefer",
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": "M",
  "typeText": "Mehrfamilienhaus",
  "part": null,
  "partText": null,
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": null,
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": "EG",
  "levelText": "#notnull",
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": "R",
  "floorText": "rechts",
  "flatNumber": "12",
  "flatInfo": null
}
},
{
"servicePointInfo": {
  "cplID": "CPL789",
  "klsID": 26035132,
  "type": "Gebaeudeteil",
  "state": "FREI",
  "stateText": "Freier Service Point",
  "plannedDisconnectDate": null,
  "recentInfo": {
    "firstName": null,
    "surname": null,
    "MSN0": null
  }
},
"buildingInfo": {
  "type": null,
  "typeText": null,
  "part": "VH",
  "partText": "Vorderhaus",
  "partNumber": null,
  "partInfo": "#notnull",
  "partAlignment": null,
  "level": null,
  "levelText": null,
  "levelNumber": null,
  "floor": null,
  "floorText": null,
  "flatNumber": null,
  "flatInfo": null
}
}
]
```

This is the matching result:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $, actual: '[{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL123","klsID":26035132,"type":"Gebaeudeteil","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":null,"surname":null,"MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":null,"typeText":null,"part":"FeH","partText":"Fernsprechh�uschen","partNumber":null,"partInfo":"vor Telekom","partAlignment":null,"level":null,"levelText":null,"levelNumber":null,"floor":null,"floorText":null,"flatNumber":null,"flatInfo":null}},{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL456","klsID":26035132,"type":"Wohnung","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":"Karl","surname":"Schaefer","MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":"M","typeText":"Mehrfamilienhaus","part":null,"partText":null,"partNumber":null,"partInfo":null,"partAlignment":null,"level":"EG","levelText":"Erdgescho�","levelNumber":null,"floor":"R","floorText":"rechts","flatNumber":"12","flatInfo":null}},{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL789","klsID":26035132,"type":"Gebaeudeteil","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":null,"surname":null,"MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":null,"typeText":null,"part":"VH","partText":"Vorderhaus","partNumber":null,"partInfo":"gelbe Haus mit dem h�sslichen Dach","partAlignment":null,"level":null,"levelText":null,"levelNumber":null,"floor":null,"floorText":null,"flatNumber":null,"flatInfo":null}}]', expected: '[{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL123","klsID":26035132,"type":"Gebaeudeteil","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":null,"surname":null,"MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":null,"typeText":null,"part":"FeH","partText":"#notnull","partNumber":null,"partInfo":"vor Telekom","partAlignment":null,"level":null,"levelText":null,"levelNumber":null,"floor":null,"floorText":null,"flatNumber":null,"flatInfo":null}},{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL456","klsID":26035132,"type":"Wohnung","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":"Karl","surname":"Schaefer","MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":"M","typeText":"Mehrfamilienhaus","part":null,"partText":null,"partNumber":null,"partInfo":null,"partAlignment":null,"level":"EG","levelText":"#notnull","levelNumber":null,"floor":"R","floorText":"rechts","flatNumber":"12","flatInfo":null}},{"servicePointInfo":{"cplID":"CPL789","klsID":26035132,"type":"Gebaeudeteil","state":"FREI","stateText":"Freier Service Point","plannedDisconnectDate":null,"recentInfo":{"firstName":null,"surname":null,"MSN0":null}},"buildingInfo":{"type":null,"typeText":null,"part":"VH","partText":"Vorderhaus","partNumber":null,"partInfo":"#notnull","partAlignment":null,"level":null,"levelText":null,"levelNumber":null,"floor":null,"floorText":null,"flatNumber":null,"flatInfo":null}}]', reason: not equal
```

Someone experience such a behaviour as well? 
cheers

--Edit due to the answer of @Peter--

This is my current build.gradle:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir file('src/test/java')
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
 }


dependencies {
    testCompile('com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.8.0.RC3')
    testCompile('com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.8.0.RC3')
    testCompile('net.masterthought:cucumber-reporting:3.8.0')
    testCompile('org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.3')
    testCompile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1')
}

test.dependsOn clean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries, forcing the maven surefire plugin to UTF-8 should fix this problem, documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#fileencoding

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```